# Half cut text in Spinner Android

Tags: android, layout, text, resize, spinner

i have one layout on Android, but if i change size of spinner my text are cut, i try custom background to spinner and try layout default but not resolve.

My XML:

```
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40px"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_custom"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="4dip"
                android:textSize="16px" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40px"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_custom"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="4dip"
                android:textSize="16px" />
        </TableRow>
```

how i can fix it?

Screen with custom background:

http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/8284/spinner.jpg

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem just better understanding on android draw9patch, before I used the editable area of ​​9patch but I saw he needed to use two types of areas, 1 - the area where the content is stretched, 2 - total area of the object. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the custom background for your Spinner an image or an xml file? If it's an xml drawable file check that you aren't using padding at the bottom.

Also try changing layout_height value to wrap_content rather than setting to 40px, that may by causing the problem.

Comment: Ty for help, if i remove 40px and set wrap_content work! but i need a small size of spinner. ty for help me.

Comment: You should try making the text size smaller, this will hopefully solve your problem. Also, if you found my answer helpful, would you mind selecting it as the accepted answer? This can be done by clicking the tick symbol next to the answer.

Comment: Bottom padding + custom background was my problem. Removing the bottom padding fixed it.